# replace() function to replace int, alphanumeric, special chars using Python3, pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, replace

All columns (NAME,MARKS,CONTACT,MAILID,SSN) except NO column should be replaced with * (stars). How can I achieve using python replace function.

```
Input:
NO,NAME,MARKS,CONTACT,MAILID,SSN
1,HENRY,89,9659651122,HENRY_99@GMA.COM,123-456-789
2,JOHN,88,8885566000,JOHN_88@ABC.COM,234-456-789
3,JACK,76,9988770099,JACK77@JAK.COM,345-678-901
4,MARY,85,4455889933,MARY22@MRY.COM,456-789-012
5,CLNT,77,5599886699,CLNT_33@CLT.COM,567-890-123

Output:
NO,NAME,MARKS,CONTACT,MAILID,SSN
1,*****,**,**********,*****_**@***.***,***-***-***
2,****,**,**********,****_**@***.***,***-***-***
3,****,**,**********,******@***.***,***-***-***
4,****,**,**********,******@***.***,***-***-***
5,****,**,**********,****_**@***.***,***-***-***
```

When I try below line of code, it is working only for Alphanumeric column values, when I include integer columns (MARKS,CONTACT) it is failing with the mentioned error message. How can i replace all required columns with a * (star) using one loop if possible.

**Code**:

```
df = pd.read_csv("input.csv")
for col in ['NAME','MARKS','CONTACT','MAILID','SSN']:
    df[col] = df[col].str.replace('[a-zA-Z0-9]','*')
```

**Error**:
raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string values!")
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dtype=object` as parameter of `read_csv`:

```
cols = ['NAME', 'MARKS', 'CONTACT', 'MAILID', 'SSN']
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv', dtype=object)
df[cols] = df[cols].replace(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]', '*', regex=True)
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

Output:

```
NO,NAME,MARKS,CONTACT,MAILID,SSN
1,*****,**,**********,*****_**@***.***,***-***-***
2,****,**,**********,****_**@***.***,***-***-***
3,****,**,**********,******@***.***,***-***-***
4,****,**,**********,******@***.***,***-***-***
5,****,**,**********,****_**@***.***,***-***-***
```

Comment: Does it solve your problem?